# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null at lat of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to double

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, http

I am getting the following error with andoroid trying to return data from PHP

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();

    result=sb.toString();
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}

//parse json data
try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

    //-----------------------------------------

    //----------------------------------------
    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("nomclt", (String) json_data.get("nomclt"));
        map.put("prenomclt", (String) json_data.get("prenomclt"));
        // map.put("adresse", (String) json_data.get("adresse"));
        //enfin on ajoute cette hashMap dans la arrayList
        listItem.add(map)
```

Script php

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("test");

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client");
    $output = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        $output[]=$row;

    print(json_encode($output));

    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you can try going into debug and put a breakpoint before the JSONArray and see if there is even anything there?

Comment: 1. check if service return valid json ... 2. are you tring to get double `lat` value from smthng like this `{some_irrelevant_val: 0, lat:null}}`?

Comment: my database contains lat and long type double

Comment: What error? You just gave us your code. What was the input? Are you saying you got the error "Error converting result"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the problem but json_encode() only works with UTF-8 values : 
http://php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem in jSON. Check the json returned by php with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.org/) by pasting the json or url of php file.

Answer (score 0):

WHich line caused the Exception prompted in Android side ? typ this for parsing JSONObject string instead:

```
map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Hope it work !